# Trouble launching informatica administrator (power center express)

Tags: localhost, port, informatica-powercenter

I have installed Informatica Powercenter Express (ETL tool) in a Win 7 environment.
The installations finished well and informatica developer works properly.

My problem is with informatica administrator, when I launch it, sometimes
works and other times doesn't work.
localhost:7009 sometimes are available and sometimes not.

Do I have to start some services?
What can I do when localhost:7009 is not available?

I have tried:

reinstalling powercenter express
starting web client services in win7
stop ans start again informatica services

Comment: What DB are you using? I can recall having some issues with SQL Server - make sure it's up&running, check if you can log in.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that each time your Informatica Services are running. (Sometimes you have to run them as administrator). 
Also check if you have started Database(before Services runninig).

Let me know.
N3k